# Storybook Won't Load Simple Component

Tags: svelte, storybook, svelte-component

I've been trying to start up a simple Storybook example from the main website, using Svelte. Unfortunately when I try and start Storybook up it just gives me the following error:

[image]

The code I have for the Storybook is intentionally very simple:

```
import { MyButton } from './MyButton.svelte'

export default { title: 'Button' };

export const primary = () => ({
  Component: MyButton,
  data: { },
});
```

And the button is just a single line:

`<button>Hello</button>`

I'm not sure what could be going wrong here as the Storybook instance seems to be expecting a component return (which the story does already). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are only trying to test Svelte development then why not use the Svelte REPL (https://svelte.dev/repl/)? It is quick way to test out building basic components without installing NodeJs and everything else needed to build Svelte apps locally. The Svelte site should really explain to new users that they can save their Svelte REPL apps (I saved one I was working on here: https://svelte.dev/repl/253ddd578806497b8b54c339490f8221). Anyway, it is an easy way to test out Svelte development online.

Comment: This provides some instructions on how to use the Svelte REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/2c06d586d890466e8dc7da6fb111efb7

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it, posting the answer here for anybody who may run into the same problem in future.

The problem is in the importing of the `Button` component. Because Svelte doesn't do split exporting of a single file (it exports the whole thing by default) I needed to define the import as a default as well.

So instead of this:

```js
import { Button } from './Button.svelte';
```

I should do this:

```js
import Button from './Button.svelte';
```

Removing the object-explosion brackets from the import.